# Is there a way to automate testing for a GNS3 network topology?

Tags: networking, emulation, gns3

I'm working on an `MPLS` backbone topology using `GNS3`, this topology includes configuration of several networking technologies such as `IPv6`, `BGP`, `OSPF`, `IPv6 to IPv4 dynamic tunneling`, `MPLS based VPNs`, `MPLS based traffic engineering`...

So I'm a beginner with basic knowledge in networking (Ipv4 addressing, basic routing and switching) and I can't just easly test if my topology works or not, moreover fiddling with configuration I've noticed that sometimes when getting MPLS config right and missing BGP config all my topology is messed up.

Given that I use Cisco 7200 series routers, **is there any way to build a test harness for my topology in order to guarentee correctness with a single push button automated process?**

Comment: Correctness - is generaly correspondance between what you have done and what you want to get. No one "push button" is smart enough to know what you want to get :).

Comment: This is achieved by defining what I want to get just like in automated testing for software.